# Delineating a section of HTML without altering document flow

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on a web application that requires me to transparently delineate a section of the DOM for usage with JavaScript. The issue is that I don't necessarily know what the rest of the page markup will look like.

I do know that the markup within the section will be 'self-contained' in that tags started within the section will also end within the section and vice versa.

I could play it safe and use comments at the start and end of the section, but this makes it somewhat inconvenient to play with in JavaScript. I'd rather be able to use DOM manipulation functions to find and modify this section.

So I guess my question is, do 'inline' elements modify the document flow at all? (Without special CSS rules) I'd like the document to look exactly the same if the tags delineating the section weren't present.

If an inline element does alter the document flow, is there a way to make an element that can be recognised by JavaScript but does not alter the document flow?

Thanks,

YM

P.S. Cross-browser support and standards compliance are important to me on this one.

EDIT: Quick note that I'm not just being lazy here. I have conducted tests and research about this and so far I believe inline elements don't alter the flow at all. (Unless they are told to with CSS) The purpose for this question is the ensure that these observations are correct and to discover any possible scenarios under which this doesn't hold true.

EDIT2: As the comments pointed out, I don't quite seem to have the vocabulary to accurately describe what I'm asking for. I also believe this question may be subjective, so I think I'll just close it and use the data tags method provided below.

Comment: I think you have to start explaining what you mean exactly with "delineating", "section" and "document flow".

Comment: Using caps because SO/SE doesn't allow linebreaks in comments for some reason.

DELINEATING: Marking the location and size of a section of HTML

SECTION: An arbitrary part of the HTML code. Effectively I'd like to treat this as a DOM node, so it will only be permitted to start and end where a regular HTML element would.

DOCUMENT FLOW: The way that elements are laid out visually on the user's screen, and also how they interact with CSS properties such as float, position and alignment.

Comment: I just realised that any element will mess with CSS child selectors and the like, so that's worth knowing. I'm interested in any similar complications to that.

Comment: It's still not very clear what's "marking the location and size". Out of the box, if someone asked me how to do that, I'd extensively use `getBoundingClientRect` and store the data I need. But I'm not sure it's what you're asking.

Comment: @YM_Industries, you should clarify the question by edition the question itself, so that it is fully understandable without reading through the comments. And your definitions aren’t very clear. “Section” normally means a large block-level construct. Do you mean any HTML *fragment*? Then you may need `div` or `span` depending on context, and the question is: do you know the context, and how are you going to “delineate” a section/fragment? Do you mean adding an element for it into the DOM? Showing a minimal example might help.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to describe the section that I want to delineate. I didn't mean a <section> element or anything, and neither am I referring to a fragment as defined by document.createDocumentFragment(), but it is simply a part of my HTML that I wish to be easily accessible via JavaScript.

As for the delineate, I'm just talking about being able to isolate the markup within that section. I'm doing DOM manipulation, I'm not fussed about the location of elements on the screen.

I'll make an example.

Comment: Actually, no I won't. I think I've got enough information, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, inline elements are part of the document flow.  Inline elements don't start with a new line but they can flow to additional lines if their contents are too large.

It sounds like you're writing some sort of visual JS code inspector.  You could target your HTML elements with JS with `data-*` attributes, which will not impact your CSS or flow.

Comment: It's actually for an AJAJ page loading system. Data tags sounds like a good plan, and then I can allow the user (developer) to deal directly with any flow issues.